# IoC container struggles with generics

Tags: catel

I have an existing program with some plugin infrastructure that currently relies on plugin classes having parameterless constructors. I'd like to offer plugin authors the opportunity to just require some infrastructure from my program by specifying parameters for the constructor.
Internally, I use some generic wrapper class to encapsulate the plugin's classes and to make them behave to the rest of my program like older pre-plugin era internal classes.

I have some placeholder here representing my infrastructure:

```
public interface IInfrastructure
    {

    }

    public class Infrastructure : IInfrastructure
    {

    }
```

Some plugin interface specification:

```
   public interface IPlugin
    {

    }
```

the plugin implementation requiring my infrastructure:

```
public class Plugin : IPlugin
    {
        public Plugin(IInfrastructure _)
        {

        }
    }
```

and my generic wrapper class expecting some plugin class

```
public class PluginWrapper<TImpl> where TImpl: class, IPlugin
    {
        public PluginWrapper(TImpl _)
        {
        }
    }
```

After registering the involved types:

```
            ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IInfrastructure, Infrastructure>(RegistrationType.Transient);
            ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType(typeof(Plugin),typeof(Plugin), RegistrationType.Transient);
            var wrapperType = typeof(PluginWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Plugin));
            ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType(wrapperType, wrapperType,RegistrationType.Transient);
```

I find out that I can resolve the "inner" plugin type:
`Assert.NotNull(ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<Plugin>());`
but I can't resolve the "Wrapper" type.
`Assert.NotNull(ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<PluginWrapper<Plugin>>());`

Am I hitting a limitation of Catel's IoC container, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The wrapper type you are registering is not open because of your call to `.MakeGenericType`. Therefore the IoC container is only aware of `PluginWrapper<Plugin>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but sorry, I don't get it.
Yes, it is only aware of `PluginWrapper<Plugin>`, and exactly that is the one I am requesting in the second call to `ResolveType`. Why doesn't it find the constructor requiring a Plugin parameter and resolve it just like it did when I called `ResolveType<Plugin>()`?

If you want to try something, I put the code into a repository at https://github.com/PatrickKursawe/Test_IoC_and_generics

Comment: Sorry, found it. I am just too stupid and by accident passed the RegistrationKind as the "tag" parameter. Leaving this away, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When not using the generic registration method, I passed the registration type in the position of the "tag" parameter by accident.

So, changing the registration part to this version:

```
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IInfrastructure, Infrastructure>(RegistrationType.Transient);
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType(typeof(Plugin),typeof(Plugin),registrationType:RegistrationType.Transient);
var wrapperType = typeof(PluginWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Plugin));
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType(wrapperType, wrapperType, registrationType:RegistrationType.Transient);
```

fixes the problem and everything goes as expected.